# MVC 4 Ajax.beginform submit - causes full postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

MVC4 Internet project

I'm using Ajax.BeginForm to do a Postback with validation and it posts back the entire page rather than just the UpdateTargetID. I've looked at other posts on SO and haven't found the answer.  I've built a new MVC4 Internet project just for testing (VS 2012 has been updated with 'ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2').

Here's my code

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
  var vM = _db.Students.FirstOrDefault(); return View(vM);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(Student vM)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  { //code if Model valid
    return Json(new { url = Url.Action("About", "Controller") });
  }
  ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "AJAX Post");
  return PartialView("Index", vM);
}
```

**View**

```
@model AJAX_Test.Models.Student
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Student"; }
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  var onSuccess = function (result)
{
  if (result.url) { window.location.href = result.url; } 
}
  // when server returns JSON object containing an url property redirect the browser    </script>
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
<div id="IDXForm">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "IDXForm", OnSuccess = "onSuccess", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{   
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
  <span>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName) @Model.EnrollmentDate.ToShortDateString()</span> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />                   
}
</div>
```

The initial view is:
[image]

After Submittal:
[image]

Source code for body after submittal:

```
        <div id="body">

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  var onSuccess = function (result) { if (result.url) { window.location.href = result.url; } }
  // when server returns JSON object containing an url property redirect the browser </script>
<h1>Student</h1>
<div id="IDXForm">
<form action="/" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="onSuccess" data-ajax-update="#IDXForm" id="form0" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="vkCszJu-fKT6zUr5ys2StOTPF6a9pZdj5k1MyaAZKo8MPweS53dUuni0C9B17NjL_GVydHa7-jI1H0F9HrYEdKxeCWq9mCeER3ebaZYLxIs1" /><span><input class="text-box single-line" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="Carson" /> 9/1/2005</span> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />                                                                                                     
</form></div>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The contents of the UpdateTargetID must be in a partial view and that partial view needs to be called from the Controller Post Action. Darin answered me through e-mail (thank you Darin). You need to use a parital view. I've tried to update his answer twice and the moderators have not done it or provided an explanation why so I'm posting my own answer for others benefit.

_MyForm View:

```
@model AJAX_Test.Models.Student

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "IDXForm", OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }))
{   
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
    <span>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)              @Model.EnrollmentDate.ToShortDateString()
    </span> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />                                                                                                     
}
```

Main View :

```
<div id="IDXForm">
    @Html.Partial("_MyForm")
</div>
```

Controller Post Action:

```
  ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "AJAX Post");
  return PartialView("_MyForm", vM);
```

Answer (score 11):

A couple of things that come to mind that might be causing this behavior:

1. In your question you have shown your bundle registrations but have you actually included them in your view or Layout? Make sure that in your view or layout you have first included `jquery.js` and then `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` (in that order):

   ```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   ```
2. The `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script is not compatible with jquery 1.9 and later because it relies on the `.live()` which has been [`removed in jQuery 1.9`](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed). So if for some reason you have upgraded your jQuery version to 1.9 or later that won't work. You should downgrade.
3. In your onSuccess callback you are redirecting to an url if the controller action returns a JSON. Have you verified that this is not the case? Because when a redirect happens using the `window.location.href` it's pretty normal that you get a full page reload and not a partial update

In all cases use a javascript debugging tool to see what exactly is happening. If you are using Firefox, then you could use FireBug. If you are using Google Chrome, you could use the Chrome Developer Toolbar. Look at the console for potential javascript errors you might have. Look at the network tab to see whether all javascripts are successfully loaded and you don't have 404 errors. Learn how to debug your javascript code with a tool. You will be surprised how much information about potential issues you might have with your code those tools will provide you.

Comment: 1-3. As I said in OP, called from layout and have verified they loaded and in proper order, using jQuery 1.8.2 (aware of 1.9 issue and avoiding for now), JSON code is commented out.  Have looked at in IE9 Developer Tools and can find no errors.  Source Code doesn't show second "Student".  I take it you saw no errors in the code I posted. Will look at more in the morning.

Comment: So can you see the AJAX call being made? Also, `IE9 Developer Tools`? Seriously? Please use a real web browser if you want to be able to debug your code.

Comment: I've updated my post. Scripts are now being directly loaded in view. I've ensured the ModelState.IsValid fails in debug. Screen shots now show Chrome/Developer Tools/Network and I've included the source code after submitting. As you can see the scripts are being loaded, the POST is happening and it GETs the two scripts. Is this what you meant by is the "AJAX call being made"? If not how do I trace that?

Comment: Can you send me a sample of your project exhibiting the error so that I can take a look? This way I will be able to immediately see the problem with your code. Right now I don't see what might be wrong.

Comment: I believe jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js now is compatible with jquery 1.9. Updated a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Scott Allen talks about it here:  http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/02/27/jquery-1-9-x-and-asp-net-mvc-4-applications.aspx Update with NuGet, Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax to => 2.0.30116

Comment: THIS IS NOT THE ANSWER. Darin answered me through e-mail (thank you Darin). You need to use a parital view.  His answer is in general good info but does not apply to this question since as I stated in the OP I already checked the things listed here. I've tried to update his answer twice and the moderators have not done it or provided an explanation why so I'm posting my own answer for others benefit.

Answer (score 1):

use:`<script src="../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>`

This JS is what makes Ajax work.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of other things to note.

1. jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js now supports JQuery 1.9. I have installed jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js version 3.0.0 and it is working with JQuery 1.9

**2. Make sure all the div tages are closed properly, including the view which contains the Ajax.BeginForm and the main view.  Also if you have @Html.Raw() in the main view or inside the view which contains Ajax.BeginForm be cautious about that too.**

Posting here to save one day of head scratching.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have your bundles config include this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you need these two includes:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

And if that still does not help, check  in web.config and make sure unobtrusive is enabled:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

And if that still has no effect, make sure unobtrusive js files are compatible with current jQuery version, whatever version of jQuery you are using, which can be found at a below URL:

http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=unobtrusive